# How to join two unrelated repositories?

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to combine two repos but I get error "repository is unrelated"..

Any workaround ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
hg pull -f /other/repo
```

You're probably familiar with repos that have multiple heads. They can have multiple tails too!

Comment: Don't forget to merge two heads after pulling repos together.